# In node.js application is it possible access two different parse-server backends

Tags: node.js, parse-server

is it possible to be a currentUser of two parse-server backends at the same time.

In a node application we need to bridge between two parse-server backends. At the present time we use effectively a curl call to access the second back end via a cloud function. But would be better (more secure) if could act as a currentUser with a Role of "superuser", to access this cloud call.

Is this possible? It looks as if all the parse SDK assume only one parse-server.